# Mask and Validate forms?

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery's a defacto standard these days, but I can't seem to find a good solution for masking and validating form input.  This seems like an issue thousands of developers must deal with regularly.  There are a few "do everything" plugins that offer form enhancements, but I need something that doesn't handle UI, just processing.  I'm hoping to find an option that I can use with many projects.

Here are the sorts of features I think are critical for this sort of task:

- Required fields
- Numeric fields
- Email fields
- Phone fields (North America primarily, but international support would be a plus)
- Website fields
- Date, Time, and Datetime fields that support mm/dd/yyyy (other formats are a plus)
- Regex fields
- Custom validation functions
- Credit Card
- Mobile Masking/validation (some masks don't work on mobile devices)
- Instant validation
- Triggered validation
- Delayed validation would be a plus (wait for input to have stopped for x milliseconds before validating)
- A placeholder polyfill would be nice, but not 100% necessary.

Are there any existing solutions to do at least most of this easily?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery mask: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin 
and jQuery Validate: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation